# Autologin to website using python

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, autologin

I'm pretty new to python and am trying to auto-login to a website once there i will then try to download a file.

I have tried the below method and have not been able to login.

Method

```
import requests
```

## Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.

```
payload = {
    'username': 'xxxxxx',
    'password': 'xxxxxxx'
}
```

## Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://service.rl360.com/scripts/customer.cgi', data=payload)
# print the html returned to see if it's a successful login page.
print p.text


# An authorised request.
r = s.get('https://service.rl360.com/scripts/customer.cgi/SC/myAccount.php')
print r.text
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm using python 2.7

Comment: it's better you use some kind of proxy to capture the actual package that was sent to the server and replay that package. https://serverfault.com/questions/2944/what-is-the-best-windows-tool-to-capture-http-traffic/2956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you got the correct url to submit the form. One thing I noticed from that website is that

```
<input type="text" name="USERNAME" id="username" title="please enter your username here" class="input" style="width: 14em;">
```

I'm not sure how they wrote the server side code, but you may try using the `name` attribute with all capital characters instead of the `id` attribute, 
so your payload becomes :
`updated like below`
update, there is still one last hidden field in the form, maybe you should include it (the url includes that `option` value, but it is not in `POST` request, server side will not recognize it), you should also include user-agent string, just in case :

```
payload = {
    'USERNAME': 'xxxxxx',
    'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxxx',
    'option': 'login'
}
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
def test():
  with requests.Session() as s:
      p = s.post('https://service.rl360.com/scripts/customer.cgi?option=login',data=payload)
```

Comment: Tried that option still no joy, do you think i should try a different package

Comment: It's not package or python problem, as I comment earlier, you need to capture the HTTP request to see what is inside

Comment: @nic.palvie, i've tried my best, if the updated solution couldn't work then good luck.

Comment: Thanks for both your answers, they both help and im now successfully logging  - One word HAPPINESS :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you haven't given any indication of the error/result. Can you elaborate on what it's returning/saying? That may give a further indication of the problem, but I assume that your second request (to myAccount.php) is simply saying "not authorised".

You have to remember that HTTP requests are completely stateless, if you make two requests, the second one won't know anything about the first... unless cookies are being used.

So from what I can tell, just because you may have authenticated correctly on that first request, that second request to myAccount.php doesn't have any notion about that first authentication request.

It's likely that the first request you make will return some kind of cookie or token, indicating that you're now authenticated. You then need to include that token in your next request to the authenticated url, so that the server knows you're ok to proceed.

Try dumping the complete response in `p` to see what has been returned. You can also do this in Chrome, by using the Developer Tools -> Network Tab. Tick `Preserve Log` and then log in manually to that site. Then go back and look at the response to your POST - hopefully you'll see something which shows that you're now authenticated. You then need to replicate that in your next request.